# Dynamically change height of UIView in Storyboard based from another UIViews height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard

Considering the following image, object B needs be dynamic in height based off number of UILabels inside it.
Object B heigh must then effect the height of object C.

I currently have this implemented in storyboard however I am stuck on these two things, What should Object B be made of? (I cannot use a stack view as my deployment target is 7.1)
it needs to have repeating list

```
[uiview] - [uilabel]
```

Object C is a UIView and I would like the height of Object B to effect its height? how can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing some code. I would calculate the heights and Y position of each object (object.frame.origin.Y and object.frame.size.height) and load them in a NSMutablearray. Then create a method that you call every time you need to resize all the elements, and in this method re-assign the relative positions and heights of each element based on the array elements: [object setFrame:CGRecMake(...)];

Comment: It can be done with storyboard (if you using), you just need to set the equal height constraint for B and C and change the ratio for them as needed, after that each time update B's height constraint the C will automatically update itself also with `layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: How will you add more `UILabels` into Object **C**?

Comment: UIlabels will go into Object B the height of Objet B will be determined by the number of UIlabels.. then the total height of Object B will effect the height of Object c

Comment: That is what i want to know, how the UILabels will get added in B? Programatically? Do mention my name in comment, as I'll get notification if you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this type of code

```
int lblY = 10; // As per your requirement
int viewBHT = 50; // As per your requirement

UILabel *lbl;

NSMutableArray *arrLbl = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1", nil];

UIView *viewB = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewB setFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewA.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, viewBHT)]; 
[viewB setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[self.view addSubview:viewB];

for (int i = 0; i < arrLbl.count; i++)
{
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblY , viewB.frame.size.width - 20, 30)];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %d",i]];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [viewB addSubview:lbl];

    lblY = lblY + lbl.frame.size.height + 10;
}

viewBHT = lbl.frame.size.height + lbl.frame.origin.y + 10;
[viewB setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width, viewBHT)];

UIView *viewC = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewC setFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewB.frame.origin.y + viewB.frame.size.height + 10, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
[viewC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:viewC];
```

Hope this will help you..!! :)